# Is there a way to use byte array on html5 source video tag?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, video

I have a byte array from Alfresco repository and I would like to get these bytes of an mp4 video file but not saving on disk, just play it directly from the bytes, on tag video of HTML5, like:

`<video src="myByteArrayRestService"...>`

Is it possible? How can I do it? 
I'm using Java, Javascript and AngularJS.

Comment: could try a data uri, but for any "useful" video would make your html ludicriously large and uncacheable. `src="data:video/mp4;base64,blahblalhblah`

Comment: Yeah @Marc B, but I would like something that works like a video file stored on server, but with bytes on client session bean.

Comment: What you are looking for is called media source extensions